# Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT while running app into android apk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, enoent

I tried building my app to android in ionic cordova using **ionic cordova build android**  but I am been faced with this error everytime a run the command. I have all my paths set in **Environment Variable** under **system variable**.

Here is the screenshot of the errors displayed:

[image]

Please, what is the caused of this errors. I have gone through stackoverflow, tried all possible soluctions I could layed my hannd on but still no progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't add `C:\Windows\System32` in your PATH variable.

Comment: Hello @Radesh, thanks for your reply. I did add it to PATH variable. Does it mean anything if I add semi colon after it?

Comment: in  PATH variable text for separate between variable add ; itself. you do not need add it

Comment: Please, is it under System Variables or User variables? because I added it to both.

Comment: in System Variables

Comment: now it is saying [ERROR] Unable to find command: cordova android build. Please what coud be the cause?

Comment: thanks a lot brother. You really made my day. Working now.